# Pre populate data in Bootstrap Form Builder

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

here is a nice form builder. I just want to know that how i can show form data on page load. Suppose any user has generated a form and saved the data into the database, next time if user wants to edit the form then all structures of form should be pre populated so that user can make changes and save again.

http://bootstrap-forms.heroku.com/

Please suggest your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could find to do this (I did it in my own project) was to alter the script heavily. When the script generates code, it strips all the form builder tags from the code. You need to alter the script so that it generates two form codes:

1. Code that can be reloaded from the database and edited again
2. Code that is actually a functional front-end form

The code you need to change is in the formbuilder JS file and is more or less build around this:

```
var genSource = function(){
var $temptxt = $("<div>").html($("#build").html());
//scrubbbbbbb
$($temptxt).find(".component").attr({"title": null,
  "data-original-title":null,
  "data-type": null,
  "data-content": null,
  "rel": null,
  "trigger":null,
  "style": null});
$($temptxt).find(".valtype").attr("data-valtype", null).removeClass("valtype");
$($temptxt).find(".component").removeClass("component");
$($temptxt).find("form").attr({"id":  null, "style": null});
$("#source").val($temptxt.html().replace(/\n\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ /g,"\n"));
}
```

You need to rewrite this so that it doesn't do all the find / replace / remove class because you need that code saved to reload all the items with the proper handles for the formbuilder to attach to.

Might be able to do as I did and just save var $temptxt to the database before it's scrubbed at all.